# Empty array as a response on postman when using node js backend with mongo db

Tags: node.js, mongodb, backend

I have a backend on node js made with a template, I´m trying to get data from a mongo db database

```
        protected async getAllUsersMongo(IUser: string): Promise<any>  {
        //const userData = mongoose.model(IUser, UserDataSchema, IUser);
        const userData = await mongoose.model('userDataSchema', UserDataSchema);
        //console.log(userData);
        return await userData.find({});             
    }  

protected async connected(connectionString: string) {
        await mongoose.connect(connectionString, {
            useNewUrlParser: true,
            useUnifiedTopology: true,
            useFindAndModify: false,
            useCreateIndex: true
        });
    }

public async getAll(): Promise<IUser[]> {
        //const db = await super.openDb();
        //const db = await super.openDbMongo(); 
        //return db.users;
        await super.connected(process.env.CONNECTION || '');
        //console.log(super.getAllUsersMongo('IUser'));
        return await super.getAllUsersMongo('IUser');      
    }
```

Comment: Try to catch some errors. For example `try { await super.connected(process.env.CONNECTION || ''); } catch (err) { console.log( err ); }`

Comment: Also, `mongoose.model` is not synchrounus, so no need to use `await`. 

Also, anything you return from a async function will be a promise. if you return a promise from a async function, it'll still be the same promise, and if you await a promise and immediately return without doing anything with the data, it's basically a pointless await, so you can just `return userData.find({});` and `return super.getAllUsersMongo('IUser');`.  Sure, the promise will not need to resolve again, so it might not do much harm, but clean code is clean code =)

Comment: Thank you I did what you two suggested

Answer (score 0):

I wasn´t using the name of the collection in mongo: UserCollection

```
protected async getAllUsersMongo(UserCollection: string): Promise<any>  {
        const userData = mongoose.model(UserCollection, UserDataSchema, UserCollection);
        //const userData = await mongoose.model('userDataSchema', UserDataSchema);
        //console.log(userData);
        var data = await userData.find({});             
        console.log(data);
        return data;
    }
```